# alias to take a parameter and exit after execution

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, alias

In my `~/.bashrc`, I have an alias called `yy` as follows

```
alias yy="youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]'"
```

But I often run it this way

```
yy <url list> && exit
```

I would like to make it simpler and convert it to a simple alias called `yye`.

```
yye <url list>
```

Would anyone please advise how to carry out this alias definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an alias for that.  Use a function:

```
yye() { youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]' "$@" && exit; }
```

The above command defines the alias.  If you want it to be permanent, put the above in your `~/.bashrc` file.

The command `yye` may be invoked as:

```
yye <url list>
```